# The given key was not present in the dictionary error in wp7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, syntax-error

When i try to reload designer it gives me this error, what it means?

Comment: It means exactly what it says.  What's the stack trace?  Are you using a custom control?

Comment: @ SLaks No, how I understand the problem is with some properties of project,but I can't understand what, because it error gives on all apges, even on newly created

Comment: I don't know, this is an error not exception, i can't debug

Comment: Open a second copy of VS and attach its debugger to the first copy.

Comment: Debug prints 279 lines, and i don't see through this lines about page loading or smth like that

Comment: The problem is with loading designer, where I should write debug.writeline to see the problem?

Comment: I have not exceptions, the error was shown on the first line of xaml file, on <phone:PhoneApplicationPage

Comment: That message is an exception that VS caught.  By turning on Break on All Exceptions, you can see the actual exception and its stack trace.

Comment: The error was on all pages, so it is because of wrong properties of project, it won't show anything in debug

Comment: You are wrong.  This is an exception thrown within VS; if you attach a debugger to VS, you will see the exception.

Comment: If so, why i have this error on newly created page, without changing that page?

Comment: I have no idea.  Use the debugger to look at the exception and find out why.

Comment: @ SLaks It was the stupiest error, when I fix my other errors and restart vs, the designer work, but I don't understand why was error, thank you for trying help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The designer try to execute the current xaml to render it on your editor. So if you have an issue in your xaml, or in your xaml.cs constructor code (and all code referenced in this constructor), this issue will occur until you resolve the problem.